# VSCODE Go to definition not working for props methods in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCODE. I can navigate to components using `F12` but not the definition of `props.onAddMeetup(meetupData)`. When i right cick  on `onAddMeetup` and try to go to definion in VSCODE, it says **No definition found for onAddMeetup**

```
import { useRef } from "react";

import Card from "../ui/Card";
import classes from "./NewMeetupForm.module.css";

function NewMeetupForm(props) {
  
  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    props.onAddMeetup(meetupData);
  }

  return (
    <Card>
      <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
       
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default NewMeetupForm;
```

Is there any extension, do i have to install for this?

Comment: As long as I know there is no need for any extension to do that. Did you name your component file with a suffix like `.jsx` or `.tsx`?

Comment: @keikai i just use `.js` not `jsx`

Comment: then try `jsx`.

Comment: @nickcoder hi, did you solve this problem by any vscode extension? I am searching for the answer of this question too. Thanks.